# aspx page with update panel not work after load in master page with jQuery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I Have a aspx page contain update panel . and load that page by using jquery ajax inside div in master page .However, the content off update panel just update for first time and other time not update.

**My Master Page:**

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Script/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="contentMain" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

**My ASPX Page**

```
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="text-align:center; margin:50px">
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="update" Width="50px" 
                    onclick="btnUpdate_Click"/>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnReg" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**My ASPX Page Code Behind**

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

**My JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        loadContent();
    });
});

function loadContent() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'Page.aspx',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: sendContent,
        success: successContent,
        error: errorContent
    });
}
function sendContent() {
    ////loading
}
function successContent(data, status) {
    $("#content .main").html(data);
    $("#content").show();
}
function errorContent(request, status, error) {
    ////error
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "for the first time"? It does not update when you reload page? Or it does not update realtime? Or it does not update when you do something (click a button)?

Comment: it does not update when for example click the button to update time.
This means that the update panel not update by any actions in loaded page

Comment: It shouldn't. You need to call function when the button is clicked. I will change my answer in a moment

Comment: I've added **btnUpdate_Click** to my ASPX Page code behind, but the time update only first time that btnUpdate clicked.

Comment: I am trying to understand why jquery registers two clicks and asp does not. I will change my answer if I find it.

Comment: I found it. Changing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided you never call function loadContent. I added the loadContent to jQuery ready() and it work on my computer.

If you have two forms on your page you have two "StateView" variables. When asp.net checks for the variable it throws error probably because the state variable comes the second time from the form of Site.Manager and not from Page.aspx. I just deleted the form on Master Page and now the button works perfectly.

**My Master Page:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head id="Head1">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="main">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**My Page.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.Page" %>

<form id="form2" enableviewstate="false" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="update" Width="50px" 
                onclick="btnUpdate_Click" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                //////////// Some Tags ///////////
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**My ASPX Page Code Behind**

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

**site.js**

```
function loadContent() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'Page.aspx',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: sendContent,
        success: successContent,
        error: errorContent
    });
}
function sendContent() {
    ////loading
}
function successContent(data, status) {
    $("#content .main").html(data);
    $("#content").show();
}
function errorContent(request, status, error) {
    ////error
}
$(function () {
    loadContent();
});
```

Comment: Ok, but I was already applying.

There's a problem that the content of the update panel only update first time that postback Occurred,
and next time not update.